# Create calculated field with colour shading

Tags: column

Have a document library with Expiry Date column for specific documentation. I need to set up a calculated field to highlight documents that expire within 3 weeks /  2 weeks and 1 week from the date they view i.e. todays date. Colour coding for 3 weeks 2 weeks and 1 week would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I have given many answers on Today and Colors here on SO in the past year

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A32871+color+today